# Google plus share using php

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

Is it possible to share some user activities (some url) to his google+ account directly with PHP (Not like a share button and having an popups or redirections)?

Please suggest me a best practice for doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is only possible with the official Google+ Share Link, but this will render a pop-up.

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

Answer (score 0):

Google+ does not allow for direct writing to a user's stream without a user's direct interaction. You can write to a user's [Google+ history](https://developers.google.com/+/history/) after they've approved your application to do so and then the user can choose whether or not to share the moments to their circles or publicly.

The Google+ history is still in developer preview.